# What is the best way to implement this using some pattern in C#?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, challenge-response

Given a data structure representing a social network, write a function that finds friends of a certain degree. Friends of the first degree are a member's immediate friends, friends of the second degree are friends of a member's friends excluding first degree friends, etc.

For example, if A is a friend with B and B is a friend with C, then GetFriendsOfDegree(A, 2) should return C since C is the only second degree friend of A (B is a first degree friend of A).

```
Method name: GetFriendsOfDegree

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Member
{
    public string Email { get; private set; }

    public ICollection<Member> Friends { get; private set; }

    public Member(string email) : this(email, new List<Member>())
    {
    }

    public Member(string email, ICollection<Member> friends)
    {
        this.Email = email;
        this.Friends = friends;
    }

    public void AddFriends(ICollection<Member> friends)
    {
        foreach (Member friend in friends)
            this.Friends.Add(friend);
    }

    public void AddFriend(Member friend)
    {
        this.Friends.Add(friend);
    }
}

public class Friends
{
    public static List<Member> GetFriendsOfDegree(Member member, int degree)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("Waiting to be implemented.");
    }

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Member a = new Member("A");
        Member b = new Member("B");
        Member c = new Member("C");

        a.AddFriend(b);
        b.AddFriend(c);

        foreach (Member friend in GetFriendsOfDegree(a, 2))
            Console.WriteLine(friend.Email);
    }
}
```

Comment: Homework? Really?...

Comment: No.. Just wa'nna to check if i did using the right way or maybe someone have another ideia to implemented that?!

Answer (score 1):

This is a graph problem that can be solved with a [*breadth-first search*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) algorithm. Your representation of the graph as an [*adjacency list*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_list) is well suited for implementing BFS algorithm.

Make a queue of pairs `(Member, distance)`, and a set of visited members. Push the initial member with the distance of zero.

Make a loop that reads from the queue, and checks if the member is part of the visited set. If it is, drop the pair and continue. Otherwise, push all friends of the current member with the distance of `d+1`, where `d` is the distance of the member that you have dequeued.

When the distance reaches the target distance of `degree`, collect the member into a list of results. Continue the loop until the queue is empty.

Comment: Cool... Good ideia but my ideia is using some design pattern... Simple and intuitive

Comment: @YuriDuretti Design patterns are about a different level of abstraction. When all you need is to implement a single method of a single class, you need an algorithm, not a design pattern.

Comment: yeah!!!  I agree,,, Just wa'nna to check if i did using the right way or maybe someone have another ideia to implemented that?!